# Erro ao salvar dados monetários: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

**Contextualização:** 

Estou usando o biblioteca ***Jquery-maskMoney** para formatar os dados monetários.Mas ao salvar estes dados ocorre o seguinte erro:

> **A non well formed numeric value encountered**

Biblioteca JQuery: http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/

**As imagens a seguir apresenta algumas telas do sistema:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Dúvida:** 

Como solucionar este problema?

Método **cadastroAprovacao** da classe **ProjetoController.php**

```
//Cadastra os dados da aba de aprovação
     public function cadastroAprovacao(Request $request)
     {
       $projeto = Projeto::find($request->get('id'));

     //  dd($projeto);
       $projeto->valor_aprovado_total = $request->get('valorInterno') + $request->get('valorEmenda');
       $projeto->valor_interno = $request->get('valorInterno');
       $projeto->valor_contrapartida = $request->get('contrapartida');
      /*  $projeto->valor_aprovado_total = str_replace(',','.',  preg_replace('#[^\d\,]#is','',$request->get('valorInterno'))) + $request->get('valorEmenda');
       $projeto->valor_interno = str_replace(',', '.', preg_replace('#[^\d\,]#is','',$request->get('valorInterno')));
       $projeto->valor_contrapartida = str_replace(',','.',  preg_replace('#[^\d\,]#is','',$request->get('contrapartida')));   */
       $projeto->nome_fiscal = $request->get('nomeFiscal'); 
       $projeto->matricula_fiscal = $request->get('matriculaFiscal'); 
       $projeto->dt_pag_autorizado = $request->get('dtAutPagamento'); 
       $projeto->observacao_autorizacao = $request->get('observacaoAprovacao');

       $response =  $projeto->salvarAprovacao($projeto);  

      //Cadastro das ocorrências dos dados da aprovação
       $ocorrencia = new Ocorrencia();
       $ocorrencia->projeto_id = $projeto->id;
       $ocorrencia->usuario_id = Auth::user()->id;
       $ocorrencia->origem = 'A'; //A origem é Automática (A) pois o sistema que registra a ocorrência
       $ocorrencia->tipo = 'I'; //É do tipo Informação (I), pois é feita automática
       $ocorrencia->descricao = "Cadastro dos Dados da Aprovação";
       $ocorrencia->dt_ocorrencia =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
       $ocorrencia->save();


       if($response['success'])
       {
           return redirect()
                     ->route('projeto.edita',$projeto->id) 
                     ->with('success',$response['message']);
       }else
       {
           return redirect()
                     ->back()
                     ->with('error',$response['message']); 

       }   
     }
```

Comment: Ruama, verifique o tipo do campo da tabela que vai ser salvo, provavelmente vc tem um campo `int` na tabela e querendo salvar uma string

Answer (score 1):

Tenta converter os valores antes de os somar e **verifica se os campos existem e são diferentes de nulos!**

Relembrando que a separação de casa decimais no PHP é feita por **pontos**.

Por exemplo:

se `valorInterno` for `10,12` ele vai ignorar o `0,12` somando apenas os `10`

```
echo (double) "10.12" + (double) 10.12;
//20.24

echo (double) "10,12" + (double) 10.12;
//20.12
if(isset($request->get('valorInterno')) && isset($request->get('valorEmenda'))){
    $projeto->valor_aprovado_total = (double) $request->get('valorInterno') + (double)$request->get('valorEmenda');
}
```